# Conditional performance in python closures

Tags: python, performance, functional-programming, closures

In the code example below, I have two higher level functions, `factory1` and `factory2`, that produce a function with identical behavior. The first factory, `factory1`, avoids having to explicitly define two different functions by letting the returned function change behavior based on a boolean from the factory. The usefulness of this is not as obvious in this example, but if the function to be produced were more complex, it would be detrimental to both readability and and maintainability to explicitly write out two almost identical copies of the function, like is done in `factory2`.

However, the `factory2` implementation is faster, as can be seen by the timing results.

Is there a way to achieve the performance of `factory2` without explicitly defining two alternative functions?

```py
def factory1(condition):

    def fn():
        if condition:
            return "foo"
        else:
            return "bar"

    return fn


def factory2(condition):

    def foo_fn():
        return "foo"

    def bar_fn():
        return "bar"

    if condition:
        return foo_fn
    else:
        return bar_fn


def test1():
    fn = factory1(True)
    for _ in range(1000):
        fn()


def test2():
    fn = factory2(True)
    for _ in range(1000):
        fn()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    print(timeit.timeit("test1()", setup="from __main__ import test1"))
    # >>> 62.458039999
    print(timeit.timeit("test2()", setup="from __main__ import test2"))
    # >>> 49.203676939
```

**EDIT: Some more context**

The reason I am asking is that I am trying to produce a function that looks something like this:

```py
def function(data):
    data = some_transform(data)

    if condition:
        # condition should be considered invariant at time of definition
        data = transform1(data)
    else:
        data = transform2(data)

    data = yet_another_transform(data)

    return data
```

Comment: Probably not.  The `factory2` result is faster  because it doesn't have to check `condition`, while the `factory1` result does.  That check is always going to take more time than not doing that check.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I see how that is true for `factory1` in its current state, but it would be nice to, for instance, have some tool to optimize fn before returning it, accounting for the invariant nature of `condition`. Not sure such a thing exists, though.

Comment: You could calculate some value `ret_val` in `factory1`, then return a function that returns that value. For 99% of use cases though, that's not going to be possible. Usually you're returning a function because you can't precalculate a value, otherwise you'd just return the value itself.

Comment: Does the difference rely solely on different *inputs* or is the difference the result of a differing process or sequence? Can the commonality be effectively separated from the difference?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh In the code I am working on I use a conditional to choose between two related transformations of some data the function is supposed to process, so I guess i end up in the 99%

Comment: @wwii I'm trying to produce a function that looks something like this:
```python
def function(data):
    if conditional:
        data = transform1(data)
    else:
        data = transform2(data)
    #More transforms on data
    return data
```

Comment: @wwii not easy to convey in comment form. Gonna edit the Q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you mean by "explicitly defining two functions", note that you don't have to *execute* a `def` statement until after you check the condition:

```
def factory3(condition):

    if condition:
        def fn():
            return "foo"
    else:
        def fn():
            return "bar"

    return fn
```

One might object that this still has to compile two code objects before determining which one gets used to define the function at run-time. In the case, you might fallback on using `exec` on a dynamically constructed string. **NOTE** This needs to be done carefully for anything other than the static example I will show here. See [the old definition for `namedtuple`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/collections.py#L247) for a good(?) example.

```
def factory4(condition):
    code = """def fn():\n    return "{}"\n""".format("foo" if condition else "bar")
    exec(code)
    return fn
```

A safer alternative might be to use a closure:

```
def factory5(condition):
    def make_fun(val):
        def _():
            return val
        return _
    if condition:
        return make_fun("foo")
    else:
        return make_fun("bar")
```

`make_fun` can be define outside of `factory5` as well, as it doesn't rely on `condition` at all.

---

Based on your edit, I think you are just looking to implement dependency injection. Don't put an `if` statement inside your function; pass `transform1` or `transform2` as an argument:

```
def function(transform):
    def _(data):
        data = some_transform(data)
        data = transform(data)
        data = yet_another_transform(data)
        return data
    return _

if condition:
    thing = function(transform1)
else:
    thing = function(transform2)
```

Comment: As discussed briefly, but perhaps not clearly enough, in the original post: The problem I'm really trying to avoid is code duplication. Imagine that the function we are defining is a lot more complex than in this example, and that the conditional is only one part of it. I want to avoid _writing out and maintaining_ two almost identical copies of a function. So your suggestion unfortunately doesn't avoid that.

Comment: My `factory4` update might satisfy your needs, but you would need to use it *very* carefully. I'm not entirely sure I recommend it. `factory5` is safer.

Comment: The `factory4` idea is really clever, but the downside is that you forgo the benefits of an a function definition that an IDE can understand, as well as readability, so not sure it is worth the cost. As for `factory5`: in the code I am actually working with (it might be worth making this clearer in my example) the conditional is used to choose between two different transformations on some data, so I can't depend on knowing what the function should return. Still a nifty idea, though.

Comment: I think your suggestion in regards to my edit seems like a good solution. It didn't appeal to me because both `transform1` and `transform2` are really simple one liners that I hadn't formulated as functions, but thinking more about it, it seems this is the only way to get this done. Thanks!

Comment: If they are simple enough, you can also pass an anonymous function (using a lambda expression) as the argument to `function`.